# VBA Macro to fill down column based on a pattern

Tags: vba, excel

I have 6 columns: A, B, C, D, E, F. In Column A for example, I would like the following sequence:

```
A1:task1
A2:task1
A3:task1
A4:task1
A5:task2
A6:task2
A7:task2
A8:task2
A9:task2
A10:task3
A11:task3
A12:task3
A13:task3
A14:task3
```

Where A stands for column A and 1, 3, 4....14 stands for row numbers

As you can see from the above sequence, task 1 is repeated 4 times, followed by task 2 which is repeated 5 times, followed by task 3 which is also repeated 5 times. I would like to keep printing this sequence till row 200.

I am relatively new to programming and would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this

**updated code**

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    t = 4
    For i = 1 To 16
    For k = 1 To t

    If i = 16 Then GoTo here:
    Range("A" & i).Value = "task" & t - 3
    If k <> t Then i = i + 1
    Next
    t = t + 1
    Next i

    here:

    Range("A1:A15").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A200"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Satish, thank you for your reply. I tested it but the result is different than what I wanted. When I used your code, the result was A1: task1, A2: task2, A3: task3, A4: task1, A5: task2, A6: task3, A7: task4, A8: task1.

Comment: I think you should raise a separate question . so that we can help or guide you . Please accept the answer if it is helped

Comment: Ok i will do that. I tried your code but the pattern I need is given in my question. Task 1 should be printed 4 times. Task 2 should be printed 5 times. and task 3 is also printed 5 times. once all this printed i want the same pattern to repeat to cell 200.

Comment: In your code, task 1 is printed 3 times, task2 is printed 4 times, task 3 is printed 5 times. I want task 1 for 4 times, task 2 for 5 times and task 3 also for 5 times. after this, i want to repeat this same pattern from task 1.

Comment: So once A1 to A14 has been filled as per my question, then from A15 I want the same printing as was done from A1 to A14

Comment: Sorry mis understood the question.. try the updated code